# getting an error when using geolib in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been struggling with this issue for past few hours. I am using Geolib to calculate the distance between two points, but I keep getting an error. Below is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, item } from 'react-native';
import geolib from 'geolib';
class ServiceListDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { latitude, longitude } = this.state;

    const dist = geolib.getDistanceSimple(
  { latitude, longitude },
  { latitude: 33.935558, longitude: -117.284912 }
);
    return (
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
        <Text>Miles:{dist} </Text>
        {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default ServiceListDetails;
```

when I add this particular line then I get the error:

```
   const dist = geolib.getDistanceSimple(
      { latitude, longitude },
      { latitude: 33.935558, longitude: -117.284912 }
    );
```

I installed geolib like below:

```
npm i geolib
```

and got the following message:

```
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.2.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ geolib@2.0.24
updated 1 package in 10.167s
```

Below is the screen shot of error message:

[image]

I get the error when I  add this line of code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give location access permission to the app. 
First, add this code to AndroidManifest.xml (android > app > src > main > AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

now it should look like

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.packagename">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
      ...some content...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

then execute a gradle clean. (I hope you know how to do it). after that, restart the server (react-native run-android/ios)

Comment: I already have this code in application. I just didn't put the code in my post because irrespective of this code, I should not get the error that I am getting above.

Comment: In my case, i  got the same error when i run the app without above code.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument needs to be an object just like the second one .. also, try using the `getDistance` function .. it should look like this :

```
const dist = geolib.getDistance(
  { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude },
  { latitude: 33.935558, longitude: -117.284912 }
);
```